# Is the name of the Uplink corporation administrator discoverable?

Tags: uplink

Normally, in the game Uplink, when I want to hack into a corporate bank I have to look up the administrator name on the Public Access Server of the corporation, so I can phone him and obtain a voice recording to bypass the voice authentication. However, in the case of the Uplink company, this is not available on the Uplink PAS, and the bank lists the administrator as "Unlisted". Is there any way I can find out the name of the Uplink admin in order to hack into the bank?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, as stated in the [FAQ](http://forums.introversion.co.uk/uplink/viewtopic.php?t=38340) on the Introversion forums, the Uplink bank is not hackable.

> Q: How can I hack the Uplink bank?
>
> A: you don't. You need a voice sample from the admin - and, as you can see, there is no admin.

I can only assume this has been done for storyline reasons, the same reason the for the missing stuff in one of the secret missions, to potect your bank account, and your person.

Remember, there are other Uplink agent out there, and if that information was known, you, the player, could be a target of those agents.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently not. There's no mention anywhere of anyone being able to break into the Uplink International Bank or of the admin name being discovered. Furthermore, I grabbed every telephone number from all the logs across every single accessible system, phoned them, saved the voice recordings and ran them against the voice authentication at the Uplink bank; no dice. Same thing with the Government systems.

There are no names left in the databases.

Comment: +1 for exhaustion, reminds me of the time I sent every uplink agent to prison.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff you mean all but those in the missing file...

Comment: @Zommuter Yeah those last ones are tricky, however you can eventually root them out by sending random people to jail and then reading the news to determine if they turned out to be one of those unlisted Uplink agents.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff Wow, I did consider trying that, but never took the effort... Did anything special happen when you turned out to be the very last Uplink agent?

Comment: @Zommuter Nope, just the smug satisfaction of ruining every hacker's life (as well as all those random innocents who got caught up in it). :D

Comment: @BiffMaGriff Well, that had certainly a more individual touch than just unleashing Revelation :-D

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you not hack it, even if you did there is only one bank account on the system; your own. This means there isn't really any point in trying!

Comment: Interesting if true, but how do you know this?

Comment: If you look at the save game file, you can see the accounts at the banks. Its a long time since I looked though. I assume nothing has changed in any recent patches!

Comment: aw, I was hoping you found some other way to hack into the system... A pity though, since that makes the other Uplink agents somehow inferior as you can theoretically amass all the money existing on bank accounts on your unhackable one - I wonder if anyone can still afford paying you for jobs after that coup...

Comment: Hmm interesting. I've never tried to trace the payments get into my account to rob my employers. I think it might just come from the ether rather than a real account.

Comment: Hm, we should check this. There goes my weekend...

Comment: It's been so long since I last played Uplink that I actually forgot job payments cant be tracked back... But now I remember that I _did_ once empty every account with at least five digits statements. Too bad that at this point I wasn't interested into doing lousy 10k jobs anymore m-/ But I suspect you're right and there is an infinite money-pot for that.