# How can I keep a sysadmin on a short path from finding me?

Tags: uplink

I have a mission that requires me to copy 90 Gqs of data from a server on a LAN.  The server is behind a dial-up poxy, and only by a few hops.

The shortest path to the server goes:

`MODEM -> LOCK -> MAIN SERVER`

The path I have to follow (and I've seen the sysadmin track) is:

`MODEM -> HUB -> AUTHENTICATION SERVER -> LOCK -> MAIN SERVER`

Even with the network's Monitor and Proxy bypassed, the sysadmin *still* jumps on the network the minute I even *touch* the main server.  I don't even have to start cracking the password or spoofing his voice authorization - just connecting to the main server is enough to trigger this.

With the short path, and the amount of work still ahead of me, there's not enough time for me to do what I need to get done before the sysadmin reaches me.

Is there some way around this that I'm not realizing?  This is a storyline mission, so I imagine there has to be - unless the random LAN generator just totally screws the player now and then.

Am I out of luck here, or should I be doing something particular to overcome this?

Comment: one thing is you can bounce around other servers.  Banks and Government servers work well as long as your last one before the main server is the "lock" you will be ok as it recognizes you are on the lan, bounce that thing like 14 times.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure I follow.  I'm bouncing off of every server listed on InterNIC already.

Comment: I am not entirely sure of it but I _do_ remember having read that bouncing through machines owned by the company whose system you want to hack (except for the last bounce) reduces the trace time. I never bothered to confirm, since around five admin account machines always seemed to provide enough trace time, without bouncing through too many ones

Comment: @Zommuter This isn't a matter of trace time.  That only affects the trace between the company's network and your Gateway.  This issue is about the Admin tracking you down *inside* of their LAN.  That's not affected by the route you take to get *to* their network.

Comment: @Iszi I'm not sure the trace time doesn't also have an influence on the time the admin logs in to start tracking you down in the LAN. But it's been a while since I last played Uplink, so this may be a fishy memory... I just mentioned it because you said you bounce through _every_ other server, which seems a bit overkill to me (However, one can find even more servers to bounce through by checking public terminals and hacking into mainframes.)

Comment: @Zommuter I'm not sure at what point any amount of connection bouncing becomes "overkill" - I've yet to test that.  All I know is that, with my usual route, my trace times are usually up around 5 minutes or more.

Comment: @Iszi it's been to long since I last played Uplink to claim actual numbers, but I'm quite certain a one digit amount of (admin) servers was enough to give me enough minutes to perform a hack in one run. Except for your mentioned time problem in LANs, of which I am not sure whether it is influence-able or not. But I [wanted to play Uplink again](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/is-the-name-of-the-uplink-corporation-administrator-discoverable/79314#comment109718_79314) anyway, so I'll try and see...

Comment: @Iszi Okay, I played Uplink again... Five admin-accounts plus the banks only gave me around two minutes. But thanks to the beneficial side-effects of a "Trace a recent balance transfer"-mission (and a Monitor-bypass) that is actually enough... But I did encounter a LAN similar to the one you mentioned (Modem->Lock->Mainframe) and the only way to make it was to quickly delete the crucial files by hand because console-deletion took to long and always restarted when aborted prematurely... Anyway, you were correct, the trace time doesn't seem to slow down the admin :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're dealing with short LAN paths, one trick is to connect to the server, crack the non-password protections first, and then *disconnect* (and remove InterNIC logs, as usual). The cracked protections will *stay* unlocked when you reconnect, meaning you only have to crack the password, and then copy files.

You can save additional time by opening both the password cracker, the file copier, and the memory view before reconnecting, and also bump up the CPU usage for the cracker so it can work faster (do the same with the file copier when the cracker is done). This should allow you to get at least *one* of the files in time, and from there, repeat until you have everything you need.

On rare occasions, this might still not be enough. If that happens, then there is unfortunately little you can do about it, except possibly upgrading your gateway to the 10Gq/s modem - which might also require downgrading your gateway overall, since IIRC, only the file server gateway can use it, but in my experience it hasn't been much of an issue.

Comment: Good suggestions here.  It sounds like you're saying there *is* the odd random occasion where the player *is indeed* just plain screwed by the random LAN generator?

Comment: @Iszi: Yes; I once had a LAN where my path was *insanely* short - I can't remember exactly how long it was, but it was *at most* a single node between the modem and the mainframe - it might even have been a direct connection between the two. While it might still be *possible* - I can't remember what my mission was, or if I completed it - you might still run against the limit of what you *yourself* can actually handle, and in those cases, you're pretty much screwed.

Comment: @Iszi It's never *completely* impossible - IIRC, it's entirely possible to mod the game and add new computers for sale that have even faster modems and much more computing power. If reality isn't working for you, hack reality :)

Comment: @Tacroy +1 for that last sentence.  Is it a quote from somewhere?

Comment: @Iszi I have no idea, but it's mine now. Muahahaha.

Answer (score 6):

Once you get connected to the main server, start mashing the back button. Then move yourself as far away from your connection point as possible. **DO NOT CONNECT TO ANYTHING ELSE.** Connecting to anything else will break your connection to the main server. The admin will then proceed to follow that path. Then, you can close the LAN view, and you'll still be connected to the main server. Download/destroy/whatever it is you need to do, and check occasionally on the LAN view. If he's close, mash back again, pick another path, and close LAN view once more to continue working the server.

Becomes so much easier when you do that.

Comment: This is the real answer. The "accepted answer" explains some tricks that moderate Uplink players already know. The fact that the Admin chases you on the LAN as well as performs an active trace, that needs to be highlighted here. Use the LAN view to backtrack and click through other hardware on the LAN (changing the dotted line) and the Admin will follow you to that item. Close the LAN view while you do this, and go back to working on the server. Then after a little bit, revisit the LAN view and change your highlighted object again for the Admin to chase you, slowing him down.

Comment: YES! This is the answer right here, forget everything else. Any decent Uplink player is already aware of the other tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to do several trips to pull all the information you need, both because of limited time and limited memory. Do you need to use any tools that are CPU-bound to infiltrate the server? If you do, upgrading your CPU could help, and upgrading your modem will help download the data faster.

You could also try working on your own speed: have the necessary tools ready to go and click like the wind in order not to waste any seconds idling.

Stealing data from a mainframe is one of the most annoying mission types, but I've never seen a mission that was downright impossible.

Comment: The gateway I'm using is pretty beefy in terms of CPU, and has the second-highest modem.  Still, I don't think there's even enough time for one file.

Comment: Added another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As [Solus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/44759/solus) mentioned in his answer, navigating through the LAN works like a charm. The other options seemed too much work, so I kept reading to find his answer. But you do not need to mash up the back button, just go back as soon as the admin has just one step to get to you... then just wait for him to go back to the router and start again.

I got this on the first try after reading this answer, thanks [Solus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/44759/solus)!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the random LAN Generator just messes up. If that happens (e.g. a direct modem link to the main server and no other connections) you have several options:

a) it is a regular mission

Just abort it unless you REALLY REALLY like pain and already have top-end hard+software.

b) it is one of the storyline missions (happened to me in ARCInfiltration)

If you have top-end hard+software, you can do it. You WILL need several trips, you WILL need the best hard+software you can get and you WILL have to react fast, but it is indeed possible.
Connect once, crack everything except the password. Disconnect, reconnect. Crack the password, after that you might have just enough time to get ~50 Gigaquads per trip before the admin kicks you (if you are really, really fast). Repeat until finished.

Answer (score 0):

Get the admin arrested 2 seconds before you enter the LAN? Whebnyou warrant an arrest, it's 2 hours until he is disabled. I'm guessing it takes at least some minutes to hire a new admin. Just check the public access terminal. I was too slow and my voice sample was too old... sounds like a fun idea at least. Not tested.