# How do you get the person responsible for hacking inside a LAN?

Tags: uplink

I already bought the LAN Viewer and most of the tools associated with LAN.
So I was able to enter the LAN, did a spoof then scan.

What now? I can't seem to get passed by it's security.

There are modems, HUB, computers, etc..

Comment: Can you access the log files? That's all you need, probably. What security does this LAN have?

Comment: Why in the world has this got 2 close votes?

Comment: They probably mistook this question as a real computer hacking question. The votes are on the off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your way through the LAN to the mainframe, using all of the LAN tools in appropriate ways. Send out probes to discover links from your current node, and navigate your way through a path to the mainframe, hacking and spoofing systems as necessary along the way. You'll want to use your Monitor_Bypass for this, since this keeps the admin from trying to track you down until you reach the mainframe.

Once you're at the mainframe, you have to hack into it. This requires spoofing the voice of the network administrator, so make sure you've called him and analyzed his voice.

AFter you hack in, it's just like tracing a hacker on any other system - go to the logs, and use Log_Undeleter on the correct log to get the next step.

Really, the only difference after reaching the mainframe is that the network administrator will track your path - if he reaches you, you're kicked off, but you can reconnect and go back to the mainframe. If you're unlucky and have a very short path to the mainframe, it might be hard to get enough time to do what you need; for that situation, refer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78364/how-can-i-keep-a-sysadmin-on-a-short-path-from-finding-me).